# Qt c++ Add module

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with c++ and Qt.
I am working on a Linux Mint system and I installed Qt in my user folder. This results having the include folder here:

```
/home/username/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include/
```

Now, whenever I try do run the commands:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

I get an error for the modules, it says for example:

> QApplication: No such file or directory

I tried a workaround by adding the line `Qt+=Widgets` in the .pro file but this did not work.
So I manually copied QApplication from:

```
/home/username/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets
```

to its parent folder:

```
/home/username/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include/
```

and this worked, but it is kinda "brutally" forced.
How could I solve this?

```
QT += core gui opengl widgets
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = cw
INCLUDEPATH += /home/username/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include path, by adding `INCLUDEPATH += <your path>` in your `.pro` project file.

In project file you should add `Qt+=widgets` instead of `Qt+=Widgets`.

Add `#include <QtWidgets>` on top of your `main.cpp`.

Comment: I tried with INCLUDEPATH += "/home/username"/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include" , "/home/username"/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include/", "home/username"/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include". With and without the "", not working :S

Comment: can you also paste the contents of your project file.

Comment: I ve pasted it, didn t copy headers and sources.